# How to display validation errors?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

Router

```
Route::get('/contact',['uses'=>'Admin\ContactController@show','as'=>'contact']);
Route::post('/contact',['uses'=>'Admin\ContactController@store']);
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Validator;


class ContactController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request,$id=FALSE) {

        if($request->isMethod('post')) {

            $messages = [
                'name.required' => 'ПОЛЕ :attribute обязательно к заполнению!!!!',
                'email.max' => 'Максимально допустимое количество символов - :max',
            ];

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'name'=>'required',
                /*'email'=>'required'*/
            ],$messages);

            $validator->sometimes(['email','site'],'required',function($input) {

                /*dump($input);
                exit();*/

                return strlen($input->name) >= 10;
            });

            $validator->after(function($validator) {

                $validator->errors()->add('name','ДОполнительное сообщение');

            });

            if($validator->fails()) {

                $messages = $validator->errors();

                //dump ($messages->first());
                dump($validator->failed());
                exit();

                return redirect()->route('contact')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            }

        }

        return view('default.contact',['title'=>'Contacts']);
    }

    public function show() {

        return view('default.contact',['title'=>'Contacts']);
    }
}
```

Template

```
extends('default.layouts.layout')

@section('content')

<div class="col-md-9">

    <div class="">
        <h2>Contact us!</h2>
    </div>

    <p>
    This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
    </p>
    {{ count($errors)}}
    @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>

                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error}}</li>
                @endforeach 

            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form method="post" action="{{ route('contact') }}">

        {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Jane Doe">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site">Site</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site" value="{{ old('site') }}" name="site" placeholder="Site">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Text</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="text" name="text" rows="3">{{ old('text') }}</textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>  
@endsection
```

The problem is that I have not displayed validation error and the message "further message". Although the validation is successful. The problem is. I don't want to display $messages I tried to walk on it with `foreach`, but laravel says that it found the $messages. Although the controller $messages displayed. The pattern also shows that the errors I have 0, but in the controller I have shows validation errors. 
What's the problem?

Comment: can you please share the validation rules and so that i can create the `FormRequest` and post the answer  because **writing validation rules in controller makes the function very large**

Answer (score 0):

try this:i hope it will work for you.

```
//controller

 if ($request->method() == 'POST') {
            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required'
             ];
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if (!$validator->fails()) {
}
else{
//validation_error();
}
}
```

and use js for validation

```
$(function () {
    $("#form_id").validate({
        errorElement: 'small', errorClass: 'invalid-feedback',
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,

            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Name Field Is Required.",
            },
            email: {
                required: "Email Field Is Required.",
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').children('small.invalid-feedback').remove();
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.closest('.form-group'));
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(window).block({
                'message': '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>',
                'css': {
                    border: '0',
                    padding: '0',
                    backgroundColor: 'none',
                    marginTop: '5%',
                    zIndex: '10600'
                },
                overlayCSS: {backgroundColor: '#555', opacity: 0.3, cursor: 'wait', zIndex: '10600'},
            });

            $.post('', $("#form_id").serialize(), function (data) {
                if (data.code == '1') {
                    swal({
                        title: "",
                        text: data.message,
                        type: "success"
                    }, function () {
                        document.location.href = base_url + '/listing_page';
                    });

                } else if (data === '0') {
                    swal("", "Something wrong while save building information.", "warning");
                } else {
                    swal("", data, "error");
                }
                $(window).unblock();
            });
        }

    });
    $('select').change(function () {
        $("#form_id").validate().element($(this));
    });

});
```